# How to avoid that Excel evaluates a formula twice?

Tags: excel, evaluation

I just started learning Excel and in the exercises I often find myself replicating a subexpression within one formula. For example, if one wants to check for possible errors when evaluating some `expression` (e.g. a `vlookup`) in order to output a sensible error message, I would try something like `if(iserror(expression);"error";expression)`. This works fine, but leaves me with the question of whether this means that Excel evaluates `expression` twice, which can have computational costs. Maybe it does not (as it would use some clever lazy strategy), but if it does, how can it be avoided? Would I have to write my own function (VBA?), or is there a way to do this inline (e.g. bind `expression` to a variable)?

Comment: The way to bind an expression in Excel is to put it into it's own cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `=IFERROR(expression, [on error msg])` to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The laziest way to fix this would be to evaluate `expression` in its own cell, and then reference that cell both places in your formula rather than copy the formula for `expression` in each place.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This option crossed my mind, but I imagine there situations that you want to do it directly, and not see intermediate steps in the spreadsheet.